# Display Array Values from SQL Table Rows

Tags: php, sql, arrays

```html
categoryID
   10
   20
   30
```

For example. Above is my `categoryID` column with values of 10, 20, and 30 PHP MySQL. What I want to do is to echo those values using an array. Like -> `10 20 30`. Below is my code. In my code. I just stored all row data from `categoryID` into my `$array` variable. My concern is. How do I echo all the values?

Thank you for the help!

```html
<?php
include ("dbconnect.php");

$sql = "SELECT categoryID FROM post";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $array[] = $row;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $array variable as below:-

```
$array[] = $row['categoryID'];
```

and to print the array try:-

```
print_r($array);
```

and to print them as 10 20 30 try the following:-

```
echo implode(' ',$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use **json_encode()** function

echo json_encode($array);

so try this

```
<?php
include ("dbconnect.php");

$sql = "SELECT categoryID FROM post";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $array[] = $row;
}


    echo json_encode($array);
    exit;

?>
```